# заменить выражение на буквенный эквивалент

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Есть 2 структуры:

```
struct bt {
int data;
}
struct info_ {
bt* root;
int id;
}
```

Есть статический вектор:

```
static vector< info_*> info;
```

Есть функция:

```
    void fn (info_ &s, int data_) {
if (info[s.id]->root->data > data_) {...}
}
```

Как определить выражение `info[s.id]->root->data` через `#define`, для сокращения кода?

пробовал `#define expr info[s.id]->root->data`, не получилось.

Сообщение компилятора:
main.cpp:1: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
 #define expr info[s.id]->root->data
                  ^

Comment: Можно. А в чем сомневаетесь? И что нужно на самом деле? Лучше модифицируйте вопрос.

Comment: Что именно не получилось? Приведите пример кода, сообщения компилятора (если есть) и вообще опишите, чего ожидали, а что *видите* на самом деле. (и отформатируйте код)

Comment: @Abyx, мне интересно можно ли именно с #define

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Да вроде без проблем работает:

```
#define LAYOUT this->layout()->objectName()

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    // ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() << LAYOUT;
    qDebug() << this->layout()->objectName();
}
```

В чем у Вас то проблема заключается?

```
void fn (info_ &s, int data_) {
    if (info[s.id]->root->data > data_) {...}
}
```

Откуда в этой функции берется `info`? Что это - глабальный массив?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
#define MYEXPR info[s.id]->root->data

struct bt {
    int data;
};

struct info_ {
    bt *root;
    int id;
};

static vector<info_ *> info;

void fn(info_ &s, int data_) {
    cout << MYEXPR << endl;
}

int main()
{
    bt *btp = new bt;
    btp->data = 1;

    info_ s;;
    s.id = 0;
    s.root = btp;

    info.push_back(&s);

    fn(s, 3);
    cout << info[s.id]->root->data << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- прекрасно работает. Выводит `1`, `1`.

Вообще, компилятор не может ругаться на инструкцию `#define`, т.к. они обрабатываюися препроцессором еще ДО начала работы компилятора.

Comment: Я в простом с++ (non-qt-project) проекте это делал.

Comment: Так тем более никаких проблем не должно быть. Я опасался проблем с MOC-компилятором, а plain-C/C++ проектах откуда проблемы могут взяться?

Comment: Как я понял по сообщению компилятора: main.cpp:1: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token #define expr info[s.id]->root->data - проблема в раскрытии значения вектора по индексу

Comment: массив - статически глобальный вектор vector< info_ *> info

Comment: @johntheripper у Вас что-то не так с переменной `info`. Я поправил ответ, все компилируется и работает.

Comment: если передавать этот вектор как аргумент функции - проблем нет, видимо функция не знает о этом векторе, если ей его не предавать. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @johntheripper, значит вектор был не совсем глобальным) Еще раз поправил ответ